# separating fraction and integers in C

Tags: c++, c

I need to separate the integer and fraction part from decimal like 4.343.

Do we have any function in C/C++ which gives the position of the decimal point. After getting that I guess we can convert to numbers using atoi function.

Thanks!

Comment: Use built-in function [modf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/modf/) for that purpose.

Comment: When you say "from decimal like 4.343", do you mean an input text string? Or do you mean a `double`?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum ...I am trying to revise c/c++... I am done with all my studies.. and in the above question ex: 5.45.. is in char * ...

Comment: @anup.stackoverflow: In what form do you want the part after the decimal? Also as a string?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ...the input is in string...and output are stored in integers..

Comment: useful link [Nearest integer floating point operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_mathematical_functions#Overview_of_functions).

Comment: @anup.stackoverflow: It's hard to see how that's useful. For example "3.1" and "3.10" are the same number. But "1" and "10" are very different integers. What's your outer problem? It seems like you may be barking up completely the wrong tree.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz.. the point is I need to find the most efficient way to separate the integer and fraction part of numbers like 2.232 i.e. number before decimal point needs to be stored in one integer and number after it in another...no matter what they are... These numbers are given to the function as paramter in char * .... ex: char * str = 9.87   -> output.. int a = 9 and int b = 87 ....Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `4.343` is a string, have a look at [`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr).

```
#include <string.h>

char src[] = "4.343";

char *p = strchr(src, ".");
```

Then you can use [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) as follow.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

if (p != NULL)
{
  *p = '\0';
  res = atoi(src);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use the [`floor()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/floor/) function to get the integer part and then for the fraction just subtract the integral part from the original value...

Comment: if you want the position of the decimal keep dividing by 10 until the floor() is 0

Answer (score 1):

You can also extract data with scanf or its relatives fscanf and sscanf

```
scanf("%d.%d",&a,&b);
```

then number of digits of a is equal to to the position of .Fraction and integer part is also stored for future use